# Looking for Pokemon Let’s go font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Hello I’m trying to find the font used in the logo for Pokemon Pikachu / Evee. I’ve attempted to find the font using likefont, whatisfont and my font to no avail.

All that I’m sure of is that the logo use a uses a commercially available font, that nintendo then made slight modifications to, just like the rest of the English Pokémon logos

Here are few possible candidates:

- **Biscuit Kids** by Jakob Fischer
- **Stockly Bold** by Febrianto Yuwono
- **Beebzz Bold** by Alexey Popov
- **JollyGood Proper Extra Bold** by Kemie Guaida

If you any other possible candidate fonts please let me know
[image]

Comment: "All that I’m sure of is that the logo use a uses a commercially available font" How are you *sure* of that?

Comment: @Scott I'm sure because all other English Pokémon logos use commercially available fonts and this is no different. I just need to find which one

Comment: If you actually [look at their logo](https://pokemonletsgo.pokemon.com/assets/img/en-gb/logo-pokemon-letsgo-pikachu.png), you can see this probably isn't a font.  It looks like these are custom created letter forms.  You shouldn't assume that this must be a font because Nintendo has used other commercial fonts.  They may have chosen not to do so in this particular case. Custom designs/hand made letters are not unusual in graphic design. There is also a possibility they may have used an actual font for inspiration. However, it's almost impossible to tell, and this would be mere speculation.